# MySql Select query combine results

Tags: mysql

Hi im having 2 tables customers and customer_items.
There is now a customer_id in both tables in the 2nd table each customer can have multiple items so the table can be like this

```
id           |    item
----------------------------
1501         |    pillow
1501         |    blanket
1501         |    others
1502         |    pillow
1502         |    blanket
1502         |    others
```

now how can i select with a mysql query the customers that have both pillow and blanket

This is my last approach

```
select custlist.id FROM customers custlist LEFT JOIN customer_items custitems ON custitems.id=custlist.id WHERE (custitems.items='pillow' AND custitems.items='blanket') UNION ALL
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a `Relational Division` problem.

```
SELECT  a.customer_ID
FROM    customers a
        INNER JOIN customer_items b
            ON a.customer_ID = b.customer_ID
WHERE   b.item IN ('pillow', 'blanket')
GROUP   BY a.customer_ID
HAVING  COUNT(*) = 2
```

- [SQL of Relational Division](http://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/divided-we-stand-the-sql-of-relational-division/)

If `item` is not unique for every `customer_ID`, a `DISTINCT` keyword is need to count only unique records.

```
SELECT  a.customer_ID
FROM    customers a
        INNER JOIN customer_items b
            ON a.customer_ID = b.customer_ID
WHERE   b.item IN ('pillow', 'blanket')
GROUP   BY a.customer_ID
HAVING  COUNT(DISTINCT b.item) = 2
```

Comment: is having statement necessary? and why?

Comment: It is counting the number of rows for the user where the item is pillow or blanket. And if this is 2 (result of the having check) then the row is returned).

Comment: Actually the total items are about 30 (enum) and each customer can have from 1-4 usually

Comment: Can a customer have multiples of the same item?

Comment: No a customer can have each item only once, btw this query is for customers that have pillow OR blanket i want to see the customers that have pillow AND blanket.

Comment: I skipped the HAVING clause was the reason, so if i want to add more items like 3 or 4 i have to change and the count right? there is not a smart way for mysql to see how many are my elements and do it without HAVING?

Comment: No. The HAVING is the smart way. The query is finding all the customers and items who had a pillow or a blanket, and for those items where the item is blanket or pillow it counts the number of items and checks it is 2.

Answer (score 1):

Slight variation of the above solution by JW:-

```
SELECT  a.customer_ID
FROM    customers a
INNER JOIN (SELECT customer_ID, item FROM customer_items WHERE item = 'pillow' GROUP BY customer_ID) PillowCheck
ON a.customer_ID = PillowCheck.customer_ID
INNER JOIN (SELECT customer_ID, item FROM customer_items WHERE item = 'blanket' GROUP BY customer_ID) BlanketCheck
ON a.customer_ID = PillowCheck.customer_ID
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this query

```
SELECT 
   a.id 
FROM 
   customer_items a
INNER JOIN
   customer_items b
ON
   a.id= b.id and 
   a.item = 'PILLOW' AND 
   b.item='blanket'
```

if you want customer name then just join customer table. If customer have multiple pillow or blanket then add `distinct`

Comment: It is propably because the elements arent GROUP BY though im not sure for that.

Answer (score 0):

SELECT 
  distinct customer_ID ,item
FROM 
   customer_items
   WHERE item in ('PILLOW', 'blanket')
GROUP   BY customer_ID
HAVING  COUNT(item) = 2